# R sem function in lavaan WARNING: could not compute standard errors

Tags: r, r-lavaan

I'm having a problem with the sem() function in the 'lavaan' package in R and I was hoping someone here might have thoughts on how I can fix it.

My model is set up as follows:

```
mod <- 'trait ~ historical1 + historical 2 + contemporary1 + contemporary2
abundance ~ contemporary1 + contemporary2 + trait
bacteria ~ historical1 + historical 2 + contemporary1 + contemporary2 + trait + abundance'
```

My exogenous variables (historical1, historical 2, contemporary1, and contemporary2) are categorical variables that I manipulated for my experiment with two possible levels. I'm treating those as dummy variables with 0's and 1's. Everything else is a numeric measurement.

I have three different variables for "bacteria" that I'm trying to look at separately. When I use the first (bacteria1), the model runs smoothly.

```
> modA<-'trait ~ historical1 + historical 2 + contemporary1 + contemporary2
+ abundance ~ contemporary1 + contemporary2 + trait
+ bacteria1 ~ historical1 + historical 2 + contemporary1 + contemporary2 + trait + abundance'
> fit<-sem(modA,data=data,meanstructure=T)
Warning message:
In lav_data_full(data = data, group = group, group.label = group.label,  :
  lavaan WARNING: some observed variances are (at least) a factor 1000 times larger than others; use varTable(fit) to investigate
> fitmeasures(fit)
               fmin               chisq                  df              pvalue 
              0.154              24.028               2.000               0.000 
     baseline.chisq         baseline.df     baseline.pvalue                 cfi 
            114.474              15.000               0.000               0.779 
                tli                nnfi                 rfi                 nfi 
             -0.661              -0.661               1.000               0.790 
               pnfi                 ifi                 rni                logl 
              0.105               0.804               0.779           -1605.897 
  unrestricted.logl                npar                 aic                 bic 
          -1593.883              19.000            3249.794            3294.572 
             ntotal                bic2               rmsea      rmsea.ci.lower 
             78.000            3234.670               0.376               0.251 
     rmsea.ci.upper        rmsea.pvalue                 rmr          rmr_nomean 
              0.517               0.000              40.988              45.826 
               srmr        srmr_bentler srmr_bentler_nomean         srmr_bollen 
              0.080               0.080               0.089               0.080 
 srmr_bollen_nomean          srmr_mplus   srmr_mplus_nomean               cn_05 
              0.089               0.080               0.089              20.450 
              cn_01                 gfi                agfi                pgfi 
             30.899               0.997               0.946               0.057 
                mfi                ecvi 
              0.868                  NA 
> summary(fit)
lavaan (0.5-16) converged normally after 145 iterations

  Number of observations                            78

  Estimator                                         ML
  Minimum Function Test Statistic               24.028
  Degrees of freedom                                 2
  P-value (Chi-square)                           0.000

Parameter estimates:

  Information                                 Expected
  Standard Errors                             Standard

                   Estimate  Std.err  Z-value  P(>|z|)
Regressions:
  trait ~
    historical1       8.722   39.607    0.220    0.826
    historical2      89.529   39.607    2.260    0.024
    contemporary1     6.737   39.621    0.170    0.865
    contemporary2   411.556   39.621   10.387    0.000
  abundance ~
    contemporary1   -36.390   81.354   -0.447    0.655
    contemporary2   424.993  123.301    3.447    0.001
    trait            -0.251    0.225   -1.116    0.265
  bacteria1 ~
    historical1      -2.342    2.455   -0.954    0.340
    historical2      -2.142    2.533   -0.845    0.398
    contemporary1    -0.268    2.459   -0.109    0.913
    contemporary2     3.410    4.059    0.840    0.401
    trait             0.000    0.007    0.031    0.975
    abundance        -0.008    0.003   -2.451    0.014

Intercepts:
    trait          1299.789   44.285   29.351    0.000
    abundance      1438.077  311.643    4.614    0.000
    bacteria1        26.805   10.717    2.501    0.012

Variances:
    trait         30569.613 4895.056
    abundance     128842.663 20631.338
    bacteria1       117.383   18.796
```

However, when I use either of the other two bacterial variables, I receive a warning "could not compute standard errors!".

```
    > modB<-'trait ~ historical1 + historical 2 + contemporary1 + contemporary2
    + abundance ~ contemporary1 + contemporary2 + trait
    + bacteria2 ~ historical1 + historical 2 + contemporary1 + contemporary2 + trait + abundance'
    > fit<-sem(modB,data=data,meanstructure=T)
    Warning messages:
    1: In lav_data_full(data = data, group = group, group.label = group.label,  :
      lavaan WARNING: some observed variances are (at least) a factor 1000 times larger than others; use varTable(fit) to investigate
    2: In lav_model_vcov(lavmodel = lavmodel, lavsamplestats = lavsamplestats,  :
      lavaan WARNING: could not compute standard errors!
> fitmeasures(fit)
               fmin               chisq                  df              pvalue      baseline.chisq 
              0.154              24.028               2.000               0.000             126.602 
        baseline.df     baseline.pvalue                 cfi                 tli                nnfi 
             15.000               0.000               0.803              -0.480              -0.480 
                rfi                 nfi                pnfi                 ifi                 rni 
              1.000               0.810               0.108               0.823               0.803 
               logl   unrestricted.logl                npar                 aic                 bic 
          -1277.674           -1265.660              19.000            2593.348            2638.126 
             ntotal                bic2               rmsea      rmsea.ci.lower      rmsea.ci.upper 
             78.000            2578.224               0.376               0.251               0.517 
       rmsea.pvalue                 rmr          rmr_nomean                srmr        srmr_bentler 
              0.000              15.075              16.855               0.078               0.078 
srmr_bentler_nomean         srmr_bollen  srmr_bollen_nomean          srmr_mplus   srmr_mplus_nomean 
              0.087               0.078               0.087               0.078               0.087 
              cn_05               cn_01                 gfi                agfi                pgfi 
             20.450              30.899               0.997               0.945               0.057 
                mfi                ecvi 
              0.868                  NA 
> summary(fit)
lavaan (0.5-16) converged normally after 115 iterations

  Number of observations                            78

  Estimator                                         ML
  Minimum Function Test Statistic               24.028
  Degrees of freedom                                 2
  P-value (Chi-square)                           0.000

Parameter estimates:

  Information                                 Expected
  Standard Errors                             Standard

                   Estimate  Std.err  Z-value  P(>|z|)
Regressions:
  trait ~
    historical1       8.723
    historical2      89.530
    contemporary1     6.737
    contemporary2   411.556
  abundance ~
    contemporary1   -36.390
    contemporary2   424.993
    trait            -0.251
  bacteria2 ~
    historical1       0.020
    historical2      -0.038
    contemporary1    -0.075
    contemporary2    -0.071
    trait            -0.000
    abundance        -0.000

Intercepts:
    trait          1299.788
    abundance      1438.077
    bacteria2         0.367

Variances:
    trait         30569.606
    abundance     128842.668
    bacteria2         0.026

    > modC<-'trait ~ historical1 + historical 2 + contemporary1 + contemporary2
    + abundance ~ contemporary1 + contemporary2 + trait
    + bacteria3 ~ historical1 + historical 2 + contemporary1 + contemporary2 + trait + abundance'
    > fit<-sem(modC,data=data,meanstructure=T)
    Warning messages:
    1: In lav_data_full(data = data, group = group, group.label = group.label,  :
      lavaan WARNING: some observed variances are (at least) a factor 1000 times larger than others; use varTable(fit) to investigate
    2: In lav_model_vcov(lavmodel = lavmodel, lavsamplestats = lavsamplestats,  :
      lavaan WARNING: could not compute standard errors!
> fitmeasures(fit)
               fmin               chisq                  df              pvalue      baseline.chisq 
              0.154              24.028               2.000               0.000             112.875 
        baseline.df     baseline.pvalue                 cfi                 tli                nnfi 
             15.000               0.000               0.775              -0.688              -0.688 
                rfi                 nfi                pnfi                 ifi                 rni 
              1.000               0.787               0.105               0.801               0.775 
               logl   unrestricted.logl                npar                 aic                 bic 
          -1414.328           -1402.314              19.000            2866.656            2911.434 
             ntotal                bic2               rmsea      rmsea.ci.lower      rmsea.ci.upper 
             78.000            2851.532               0.376               0.251               0.517 
       rmsea.pvalue                 rmr          rmr_nomean                srmr        srmr_bentler 
              0.000              15.160              16.949               0.077               0.077 
srmr_bentler_nomean         srmr_bollen  srmr_bollen_nomean          srmr_mplus   srmr_mplus_nomean 
              0.086               0.079               0.086               0.079               0.086 
              cn_05               cn_01                 gfi                agfi                pgfi 
             20.450              30.899               1.000               0.991               0.057 
                mfi                ecvi 
              0.868                  NA 
> summary(fit)
lavaan (0.5-16) converged normally after 119 iterations

  Number of observations                            78

  Estimator                                         ML
  Minimum Function Test Statistic               24.028
  Degrees of freedom                                 2
  P-value (Chi-square)                           0.000

Parameter estimates:

  Information                                 Expected
  Standard Errors                             Standard

                   Estimate  Std.err  Z-value  P(>|z|)
Regressions:
  trait ~
    historical1       8.723
    historical2      89.530
    contemporary1     6.737
    contemporary2   411.556
  abundance ~
    contemporary1   -36.390
    contemporary2   424.993
    trait            -0.251
  bacteria3 ~
    historical1       0.098
    historical2       0.095
    contemporary1    -0.102
    contemporary2     0.204
    trait            -0.000
    abundance        -0.000

Intercepts:
    trait          1299.788
    abundance      1438.077
    bacteria3        19.984

Variances:
    trait         30569.585
    abundance     128842.707
    bacteria3         0.864
```

I did some research about this warning but nothing seems to help. Does the model just fit really poorly with the other two variables?

Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

```
> str(data)
'data.frame':   78 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ X            : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ historical1  : int  0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ historical2  : int  0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 ...
 $ contemporary1: int  0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 ...
 $ contemporary2: int  1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 ...
 $ trait        : num  2202 1935 1371 1978 1130 ...
 $ abundance    : num  1011 1757 1347 1578 1674 ...
 $ bacteria1    : num  30.39 6.69 7.58 6.05 8.47 ...
 $ bacteria2    : num  -0.0356 0.0304 0.1344 -0.0497 0.265 ...
 $ bacteria3    : num  19.4 18.1 20 18.1 18.4 ...
```

Erica

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anyone was wondering, I did eventually figure this one out. There was apparently a scaling issue between the variables in the model. It can be fixed using the scale() function.

```
data[,c(19,21)]<-scale(data[,c(19,21)],center=FALSE,scale=c(100000000,0.01))
```

Where column 19 corresponds to the 'bacteria2' variable and column 21 corresponds to my 'bacteria3' variable. The bacteria2 variable was roughly 10^7 while bacteria3 was roughly 10^-2. Rescaling them to 10^1 or 10^2 fixes both warnings produced in the code above and sem() successfully calculates standard errors.